# What is the real role of the queen in UK in these days?

Tags: government, united-kingdom, society, monarchy

What is the role in the government or social of this Queen in UK in these days?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This site sums it up pretty well:

https://www.royal.gov.uk/MonarchUK/HowtheMonarchyworks/HowtheMonarchyworks.aspx

"As Head of State, The Monarch undertakes constitutional and representational duties which have developed over one thousand years of history. In addition to these State duties, The Monarch has a less formal role as 'Head of Nation'. The Sovereign acts as a focus for national identity, unity and pride; gives a sense of stability and continuity; officially recognises success and excellence; and supports the ideal of voluntary service."

Essentially the queen of England is a figure head without much political or executive power. She has more of a leadership role than an administrative role.  She is a voice of influence and guidance more than a voice of power.  She also performs many of the ceremonial duties that the US president performs like giving medals of honor and such.